# Outlook Add-in is just showing blank

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

We have deployed an Outlook Add-in to Office 365 Admin centre, which have went well.

The issue is that when we're opening the app, it only shows a blank picture.

I'm trying to host a powerApp through Iframe, and I guess it's because we're hosting the MessageRead file and functionfile in a blob storage in Azure?

When our exchange admin deploys the code/manifest through VS and refrencing the files like this (~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon64.png) in the manifest it works.

When I try to sideload the addin myself, it also shows up like the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UZ8y.png),

Best Regards

HH

Comment: Do you get the same picture in Outlook online as well? It would be great to look at the manifest file? Do static HTML pages work correctly for the task pane?

Comment: It will probably help if you can provide some more details. Does the rest of your HTML load? Do you experience this only on Outlook Web Access? Or does it also happen on Win32 or Mac Desktop clients? Does it work fine if you host the HTML somewhere else? What is it supposed to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use runtime logging to debug your add-in's manifest as well as several installation errors. This feature can help you identify and fix issues with your manifest that are not detected by XSD schema validation, such as a mismatch between resource IDs. See [Debug your add-in with runtime logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging) for more information.

Also clearing the Office cache often fixes issues related to stale code. This guarantees the latest manifest is uploaded, using the current file names, menu text, and other command elements. To learn more, see [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache).